# Kafka: как увидеть список топиков?

Tags: apache-kafka

я оказался в странной ситуации.

Есть Kafka-сервер разработчиков, назовём его m1.dev.mysite.ru

Располагается он внутри локалки, и я его прекрасно пингую.

Далее я читаю ["квикстарт"](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart), устанавливаю себе все по инструкции и пробую команды:

```
    bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server=m1.dev.mysite.ru:2181 --list
```

получаю ошибку:

```
    ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listTopics
```

Пробую по-другому:

```
    bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper m1.dev.mysite.ru:2181
```

получаю скаловский стектрейс, суть которого в том, что  `zookeeper is not a recognized option`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так, и как мне получить список топиков?

Спасибо.

**Дополнение:**

Похоже, я сам дурак: zookeper то я не поставил. А, как я понимаю, он должен быть установлен локально, чтобы подключиться к "чужому" серверу Kafka.

Подскажите, ведь это так?

Comment: `--bootstrap-server=m1.dev.mysite.ru:2181` - 2181 это обычно порт зукипера, а кафка обычно на 9092

Comment: "он должен быть установлен локально, чтобы подключиться к "чужому" серверу Kafka." сервера Кафки хранят в Зукипере метаданные, они без Зукипера даже не поднимутся. Ставить свой локальный Зукипер имеет смысл только если потом ставить свою локальную Кафку.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Да, я чуть позже разобрался, что просто с портами напутал.